# Cant add the files in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have developing a Asp.net webApplication with C#.

I downloaded a CSS file and stored in Sytles folder. The image description is shown below.

[image: CSS File downloaded]

Now in aspx page when i tried to add the href link its not showing the files. I have rebuild the solution. But still its not showing. Do i need to add any references?

[image: Can't find the files]

How to overcome this?

Comment: is your problem solved?

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the files in your project.

Read [MSDN: How to: Add Existing Items to a Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9f4t9t92(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You have to include the folder in your project first. Here is a step by step about how to include files/folders in your project.

For example, I have a project, now I want to include a XML file named `Places.xml` to my project.

It won't be visible in your solution explorer at first. **You have to click `Show All Files` to see it.**

[image: Show All Files]

**Right click the file, choose `Include in Project`.**

[image: Include in Project]

**Now, you can see its icon turn brighter.**

[image: Done]

Re-build the project, and that's all.